# AS3 private vs public functions

Tags: actionscript-3, function, class, private, public

What are the best practices on using `private` and `public` functions in AS3?

If I am unsure as to which it should be, should I always use `private`?

Comment: Don't forget about `protected` - this is the same as private but sub classes (classes that extend it) can also access the methods/vars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is irrelevant to the language you use, Maybe language-agnostic tag suits for this question. You can find an answer in any object oriented language book.

Ιn a nutshell, you use *private* when you don't want other objects having access to those functions in contrary with *public*.

Something that you might see a lot is that *private* functions usually utilize properties that resides inside the object and there are in the same scope. This happens when the internal process doesn't concern other objects, for good structuring and readability reasons.

```
public class ExampleClass {

   private var message : String;

   public function publicMethod(argument:String):String {
       argument = "passing argument utilization";
   }

   private function privateMethod():void {
       this.message = "manipulate object attribute";
   }
}
```

Another term that you might want to see is *encapsulation*, and the bound between private properties and public functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use private methods whenever you don't need to expose the method/variable to everyone else. It will ease the debugging and after when you re-read your code. If you're not sure of which one to use, ask yourself:" Will i need this method externally ?"